# how to stop a bash programm (while loop) when press key or combination?

Tags: bash, loops, signals

I have a while loop, I would like to stopped it when the user presses the letter "s" on the keyboard.

I should manage the problem with a "trap" and using relative signal, which by default block has with combination "ctrl + c", but I should have the same effect by pressing "s".

(I do not have to use the command read)

Where to place the commands?

could you explain me ?

Thank you

The code:

```
!/bin/bash

while true

do

echo text text text text

done
```

Comment: Could you paste a code sample ? How fast is an iteration of your `while` loop ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and add sample input and expected output. For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Simply:


!/bin/bash

while true

do

echo text text text text

done

Answer (score 0):

Following what [Aserre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057091/aserre) says:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty -echo -icanon -icrnl time 0 min 0; fi

keypress=''
while [ "$keypress" != "s" ]; do
  echo text text text
  keypress="`cat -v`"
done

if [ -t 0 ]; then stty sane; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you don't want to use `read` as it would be as simple as

```
#! /bin/bash

while :
do
    echo "text text text"
    read -t 0.3 -n 1 k
    [[ "$k" == 's' ]] && break
done
```